# Is it possible to add an HTTP header from AWS Custom Auth on API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using Custom Auth on AWS API Gateway, but I would like to add an extra HTTP header depending on the result. Does anyone know if this is possible, or how to do it. If it is not, is there an idea of if or when this will be possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We recently added support for this. Docs should be up soon.

Now you can return an object like this from the authorizer function:

```
{
  "principalId": "xxxxxxxx", // The principal user identification associated with the token send by the client.
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow|Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<appId>/<stage>/<httpVerb>/[<resource>/<httpVerb>/[...]]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context" : {
    "key" : "value",
    "numKey" : 1,
    "boolKey" : true
  }
}
```

Arrays and objects aren't allowed, only string/number/boolean as valid JSON. The root key must be named `context`.

You can access those values in the request $context like so:

```
$context.authorizer.key -> value 
$context.authorizer.numKey -> 1
$context.authorizer.boolKey -> true
```

So to answer your question, you wont' be able to conditionally ***add*** the header, but you could set the header value to `$context.authorizer.yourKey` and if `yourKey` isn't set in the authorizer response, the header value would be blank (but the header would still be sent).

**Edit:**

Docs are live http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html

Comment: Mind marking as correct answer? This might be the most complete documentation on the new functionality until our docs go live :)

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS, does this work if your using Mock?  I'm trying to use $context.authorizer.principalId in the Integration Request body mapping and it's throwing an error.

Comment: The Integration Request body mapping has to be exactly like `{ "statusCode":200}` for Mock integration. If you need to mock the response payload, you should use a Integration Response mapping template.

Comment: Just a caveat, Lambda proxy integration loses the type of context values, i.e. all of string, number and boolean values would be passed as strings.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working after a day of pulling my hair out and hopefully I can save someone from that. It adds a bit more to Jacks' response.
Basically, you can dynamically add headers by using **Body Mapping Templates**

1. Create and Authorizer Lambda (you can use the authorizer blueprint lambda to get started), do your business logic to create the AuthPolicy and populate the **context** object with the key/values.
2. On the API Gateway, select the resource, click on **Method Request** and set the Auth to your Authorizer lambda
3. Open **Method Execution**, select the Integration type and make sure to **unselect** Use Lambda Proxy integration (if your request points to a lambda)
4. Add a **Body Mapping Template** - create one from the template and this is where you have access to $context.authorizer.key
5. Add the following to your template (just under "body-json" : $input.json('$')," is fine)

> ```
> "headers": {
>      "key-header" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($context.authorizer.key)",
>      #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
>          "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" 
>          #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
>      #end },
> ```

This will add a new header called "key-header" and also forward all the original headers allowing you to append additional information like user_id, user_role, etc to the upstream service.

Answer (score 4):

I tried Emanuel Canha's answer above, but that no longer seems to work. The way I got it to work yesterday (5 June 2019) is to

1. Create the lambda
2. Add the lambda under **Method Request** as your authorizer
3. Open **Integration Request**
4. Open HTTP Headers
5. Add a header with the name you want (`key-header` in the above example)
6. Use `context.authorizer.yourKey` as the *mapped from* entry. (Note that you [do not use the $ in this field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters).)

Answer (score 1):

You can only get PrincipalId from authorizer result, in your integration request, you can map a header value using `context.authorizer.principalId`