# Added claims from AWS custom lambda Authorizer, how to access those claims in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I have created AWS custom lambda Authorizer, which is validating token and add claims in APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse with Context property.

```
private APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse AuthorizedResponse(TokenIntrospectionResponse result) // result with claims after validating token
    {
return new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse()
        {
            PrincipalID = "uniqueid",
            PolicyDocument = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy()
            {
                Statement = new List<APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement>
                {
                    new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement()
                    {
                        Effect = "Allow",
                        Resource = new HashSet<string> { "*" },
                        Action = new HashSet<string> { "execute-api:Invoke" }
                    }
                }
            },
            Context = PrepareRequestContextFromClaims(result.Claims) //APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput
        };
}

private APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput PrepareRequestContextFromClaims(IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims)
    {
        APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput contextOutput = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput();

        var claimsGroupsByType = claims.GroupBy(x => x.Type);
        foreach (var claimsGroup in claimsGroupsByType)
        {
            var type = claimsGroup.Key;
            var valuesList = claimsGroup.Select(x => x.Value); 
            var values = string.Join(',', valuesList);
            contextOutput[type] = values;
        }

        return contextOutput;
    }
```

Added this lambda authorizer with API GW method request.

For integration request, I have added HTTP Proxy request, which is an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

I am trying to access claims from the headers, that were added by authorizer in Web API routes, but not getting any claims.

```
_httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers
// not getting with headers

_httpContext.HttpContext.Items["LAMBDA_REQUEST_OBJECT"] as APIGatewayProxyRequest
// not getting with this as well
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I am assuming you need to add the custom headers before you send the request to your backend. API Gateway lets you use mapping templates for this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html

Comment: An AWS engineer says *Arrays and objects aren't allowed, only string/number/boolean as valid JSON* https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644554/495455

Comment: If we try to access in lambda function(Integration request) we are getting it via APIGatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext.Authorizer["claimkey"] , but with web api we are not getting it.                                              


looks like it now supports the ArrayKey and MapKey as well : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html

Answer (score 1):

Needs to configure claim key value with API Gateway's Method & Integration request.

For example, if custom lambda authorizer validates token and add claim 'role' in Context of APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse => we have to add optional role in headers with 'Method Request' and also need to add header with 'Integration request' as (Name : role, Mapped from : context.authorizer.role).

then after we will get 'role' from headers using _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers['role'] with .Net Core 6 Web API.